# "Smart" SQL Update using ListBox

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-4.0, listbox, sql-update

I am developing a project which access a database in sql server 2012 through C# and performs CRUD modifications on it. Here is the main form:

[image]

both listboxes on the right are used to deal with informations contained in an intermediate tables (many-to-many relationship). Here is how they work: Basically, you choose types and abilities from the comboboxes, then click on 'add' and they are added in the respective listboxes. To delete items in the listboxes, you just need to select one item and then click 'delete'.
Here's another print to clear any doubts:

[image]

On the first print I've provided here, you will see a 'Bulbasaur' data. The PokémonID = 1 is represented by the 'Bulbasaur'; TypeID = 1 and 12 are 'Grass' and 'Poison', respectively; and AbilityID = 1 is 'Overgrow'.

I was trying to create an update function (update_click) using sql queries (SqlCommand, SqlDataReader and so on...), but **without** deleting the whole associations of a pokémon and its types (and abilities) and then re-adding them, based on the new modifications on the listboxes. I want to avoid it in order to save some memory in cases that some pokémon may hold thousands of types and abilities...

Is it possible? If necessary, I can send you my C# project for more details.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?lwk4dairda9uv2o

Comment: if you want to continue answering you plz check your previous questions and mark correct answer , even vote it up we spend time for providing you any answers :)

Comment: any thoughts on the below answers Mudkip?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it sounds like what you are saying you'd like to do is to only "send the changes" to the database:

- add any abilities that were not there before;
- remove any abilities that were in the database but have been removed

If that's the case then what you need to be able to do is simple set operations:

- Set Union
- Set Intersect
- Set Difference

while you can perform these operations using simple arrays or lists, it is much more efficient to use an actual set implementation such as a generic HashSet<>. With a correct implementation using sets or hash tables you ca achieve linear-time performance.

I hope this helps point you in the right direction..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a combination of:

1) Use table-valued parameters to send all the data (in its present state in your listboxes) to your T-SQL query or stored procedure at once

2) Consider using the [`EXCEPT` and/or `INTERSECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) operators (as well as any necessary LEFT or RIGHT JOIN) to compare the contents of your table-valued parameter (essentially a table itself) with the data currently in the underlying tables

3) UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT accordingly